# Create custom license page

Tags: flutter, material-ui

I'm using showLicensePage function in my app's drawer.

I want to customize the content of that page, not only name, version and icon. I want to customize the body, adding my own terms and conditions.

Comment: If you want to create your own Terms & Conditions, I think you can't do that in `showLicensePage`. Because it only contains the licenses. If you want to create a T&C or any other kind of legal documents, I recommend creating a new page for you T&C.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there's no way to change the content and structure of the screen.

However, you can access all license data used by your application from the [LicenseRegistry class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/LicenseRegistry-class.html) which gives you a stream of all used licenses. You can then extract the data from each [LicenseEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/LicenseEntry-class.html) element in the stream and and build that data into your own custom widget.

Here's an example:

```
FutureBuilder<List<LicenseEntry>>(
    future: LicenseRegistry.licenses.toList(),
    // initial data ...,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<LicenseEntry>> snapshot) { // Check for null data and errors ...
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text('Package name: ${snapshot.data.first.packages.first}'),
          Text('License paragraph snippet: ${snapshot.data.first.paragraphs.first.text}')]);
```